# SQL inner select to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, datagrid

This *thing* is driving me crazy.

I think its not that complicated but I don't get it.

I have this working SQL statement and I need the Linq statement for it.

```
select 
    a.id, a.date, 
    (select top 1 b.price from b where a.id = b.id and a.date >= b.date) as price 
from a;
```

For explanation:

I have a table a with articles and a table b with a price history.

Now I need a datagrid where I can enter new entries for table a (so a view is not working) and after saving its showing me associated price

I hope I could express myself understandably

Comment: So what have you tried already?  I dont see any c# code in your post

Comment: At first I tried to write in a view but visual studio said I could not do that :P
Then I tried to rewrite the inner select into a join because (I think) I can do linq joins. But with join i dont get how to join only top 1 ... so there is no code yet

Comment: `example.Select(x => sample.Where(c => c.Id == x.Id and c.Date == x.Date))` should give you a solid point to figure it out.

Comment: I'd use `x => x.First(<same condition>)`. Saves the step of later doing `.First()` as SQL subquery only selects top 1.

Comment: @JustinasMarozas Yeah, that'd be better.

Comment: i really thank you guys! I knew it wasn't that hard :P and sorry for my bad english, thanks @marc_s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For translating SQL to LINQ query comprehension:

1. Translate `FROM` subselects as separately declared variables.
2. Translate each clause in LINQ clause order, leaving monadic operators (DISTINCT, TOP, etc) as functions applied to the whole LINQ query.
3. Use table aliases as range variables. Use column aliases as anonymous type field names.
4. Use anonymous types (new { }) for multiple columns
5. Left Join is simulated by using a into join_variable and doing another from from the join variable followed by .DefaultIfEmpty().
6. Replace COALESCE with the conditional operator and a null test.
7. SELECT * must be replaced with select range_variable or for joins, an anonymous object containing all the range variables.
8. SELECT fields must be replaced with select new { ... } creating an anonymous object with all the desired fields or expressions.
9. Proper `FULL OUTER JOIN` must be handled with an extension method.

For your query:

```
var ans = from ra in a
          select new {
              ra.id,
              ra.date,
              price = (from rb in b
                       where ra.id == rb.id && ra.date >= rb.date
                       select rb.price).First()
          };
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which syntax you're aiming for, but one of these should do the trick. I haven't tested it though.

```
from xa in a
select new
{
    id,
    date,
    price = (
        from xb in b
        where xa.id == xb.id && xa.date >= xb.date
        select xb.price
    ).First() // or .FirstOrDefault() if you want to allow null prices
};
```

or

```
a.Select(xa => new
{
    id,
    date,
    price = b.First(xb => xa.id == xb.id && xa.date >= xb.date) // or .FirstOrDefault() if you want to allow null prices
});
```

Comment: May want to do `FirstOrDefault` so the query doesn't implode if more than one is returned.

Comment: @Greg I think you are confusing `First` with `Single`.

Comment: @JustinasMarozas I think you forgot your range variables in the query comprehension form.

Comment: Good point, @Greg. Updated the answer. I generally avoid '*OrDefault()' methods as in many cases I'd rather have an exception telling me my data is bad than null value though.

Comment: @NetMage Yeah, I always confuse those two.